# problems an opaque on the interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

i'm studying iOS programming. but i have a problem, which is opaque.

now assume. i have two image views.

when i write code, it works. code is here.

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"something1"];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"something2"];
imageView2.opaque = NO;
[controller addSubView:imageView1];
[controller addSubView:imageView2];
```

now, imageView2 is on the imageView1. but imageView2's property opaque set to NO.

so i can see imageView1 only. ok. that's what i want.

but i want to do more easily. so i use interface builder.

i have two image views. one is wire up IBOutlet ImageView *imageView1

and another one is IBOutlet ImageView *imageView2.

and i set the imageView2's inspector. and uncheck opaque.

and i build it. so i think it's same effect as code above.

but imageView2 is on the imageView1.

it's not disappear.

why is that?

why code can work but interface builder not?

Comment: I'm guessing the above isn't your real code as you are initialising imageviews with a string, and if you'd got past that stage, you would be seeing imageview 2 only as that is added second so would be on top of imageview 1.

Comment: yes. it's not my real code. and yes that's my mistake. it's not a string. it's image actually. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIView's opaque property is used for determining whether the view can optimize compositing operations.  You should be setting the alpha property.

Comment: is any choice? because imageView2's size is bigger than imageView1. in this case, if i set imageView1 on the imageView2, everything's all right. i can see imageView1 and imageView2 both.(of course i can't see imageView2's some area because that area overlap imageView1)  but when i have multiple imageViews, and i want to add one imageView. it's larger than some image, which i already added. then i have to rearrange all of this?

Comment: If you are using Interface builder to add both image views on the screen at the same time, just re-order them so that image view2 is behind image view 1,  in our code above, you add them in that order 1, then 2   in interface builder, drag image view 2 so that it is above image view 1.  If you are trying to just switch between two images, you can either set one of them to hidden, or just add the UIImageView in Interface builder, and swap the UIImage that it holds when you need to switch images.  If you are trying to mask the bottom image, then you need to investigate how to mask an image.

Answer (score 1):

Subviews added in code will be placed on top of each other in the order you call `addSubview`. To add a subview in a specific Z-position use `insertSubview: atIndex:`.

In interface builder you have to manually control the layering using the menus (send to back, etc), otherwise the last added view will be on top.

The `opaque` setting should be set to `YES` if you want a view to completely obscure the view underneath. If you want the views underneath to show through, set `opaque` to `NO` and set the alpha (transparency) as you wish.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i set opaque to NO. and set alpha to 0. i can't see one image at all. i just want to hide overlap area. not all area of image. can i do this?